# Export XYZ matrix selecting positive Z data points in three files and keeping the matrix form

Tags: matrix, export, filtering

The following code saves XYZ points in a separated file but keeping the matrix shape.

```
p = Flatten[
  Table[{Sin[x], Cos[y], z}, {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2, Pi/2}, {y, -Pi/2, Pi/2, 
    Pi/2}, {z, -Pi/2, Pi/2, Pi/2}], 1]
MapIndexed[
 Export["B" <> Apply[IntegerString, #2] <> ".dat", #, "Table"] &, 
 Transpose[N[pp], {2, 3, 1}]]
```

I would like to have the same functionality but saving only the coordinates with positive Z.

Comment: Do you mean you want your Table to go from zero to pi over two `{z, 0, Pi/2, Pi/2}` instead of -pi over two to pi over two `{z, -Pi/2, Pi/2, Pi/2}`?

Comment: @Ruud3.1415 Thanks to your comment. No, this is just an example. The matrix I want to save is bigger, and Mathematica computes it in a Notebook that imports data from files.